# Back office credit card contribution - membership stays pending

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

CiviCRM 4.6

Issue: When a credit card payment is made on the backend for a membership, the membership status stays pending even after a successful transaction.

The membership needs to be edited and saved (without changing anything) and the status updates correctly to current.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not the same issue but possibly related - we are having the same "status change" issue in 4.6.4 with memberships not properly moving to grace or expired where editing and saving the membership without making changes updates to the correct status.

Comment: I am having the same issue on CiviCRM 4.7.8 when adding membership payments through the CiviBanking extension (or manually add and link them to the membership). Only after edit&save of the membership without changes "Pending" switches to "New"